# Looking for a story about a tin badge set with a dull jewel that could scratch diamonds

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a short story about a recently deceased shopkeeper who earns and transmits gold to be alloyed into a superstrong metal in support of a future rebellion against tyranny.  "A weakminded victim of fraud," say the police investigators.  The shopkeeper's effects include a cheap tin badge set with a dull jewel which, if checked, would be found able to scratch diamonds.

Answer (score 7):

This is ["Time Fighter"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57323) by [Fritz Leiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fritz_Leiber) which you can find in his collection [*A Pail of Air*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?945). It was first published in [*Fantastic Universe*, March 1957](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?89778+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantastic_Universe_v07n03_1957-03#page/n77/mode/2up). Here is a plot summary from NESFA's [Recursive Science Fiction](https://data.nesfa.org/Recursion/recursive_L.htm) page:

> George Mercer is a jeweler and a science fiction fan. He is also the victim of Dave Kantarian's time-travel swindle. Kantarian meets George at the local SF club and pretends to be an agent from the 70th century; the people of this time need gold and silver, which they will transform into armor, in their interstellar war. One proof of authenticity is the tendrils among his hairs. Much precious metal is "transferred forward in time." When Kantarian is found dead Treasury agents investigate but George is not implicated. He will not believe that Kantarian was only a crook. The Treasury agent gives George a cheap "Time Fighter" pin found in the transfer device. George later finds that the dull metal of the pin will scratch diamond.